# Issue with language-servers in Neovim

Tags: c, lua, neovim

I've setup lsp under Neovim correctly and installed a language-server for C and another one for Lua. But when I open a lua/c file, I always get that error:

```
Spawning language-server with cmd: `clangd` failed with error message: EACCES: permission denied
```

I get the exact same error with lua-files:

```
Spawning language-server with cmd: `lua-language-server` failed with error message: EACCES: permission denied
```

My language-servers are:

- clangd (for c)
- sumneko_lua (for lua)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your neovim installed? snap?

Comment: Check your permissions for your C/Lua language servers binary. According to your error messages, you haven't the permissions to execute it.

Comment: I have similar problem under WSL.. I needed to cast `chmod a+x` on `lua-language-server` and `clangd` files (those files are cmd to start the language servers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows and tried to install `clangd` using `npm i -g clangd`, then you have to actually [`clangd-windows`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clangd-windows) using

```
npm i -g clangd-windows
```

Alternatively, you can also install `clangd` using `scoop`

```
scoop bucket add main
scoop install clangd
```